# How can I access DOM Element properties from Go WebAssembly?

Tags: go, webassembly

I'm trying to extend the "Hello WebAssembly" example from https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WebAssembly. As given, the example simply prints a message to the console. I wanted to add some code using `syscall/js` to replace the body element content.

The attempt below fails to build:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "syscall/js"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, WebAssembly!") // original example
    // I added
    doc := js.Global().Get("document")
    body := doc.Call("getElementById", "thebody")
    body.innerHTML = "Dynamic Content"
}
```

When I try to build with `$ env GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm go build -o main.wasm`
I get :

`./wasm.go:14:6: body.innerHTML undefined (type js.Value has no field or method innerHTML)`

Not surprising when you think about it, but I don't see an example in the doc at https://godoc.org/syscall/js that explains how to get and set element properties.

Comment: 1) "This package is EXPERIMENTAL. Its current scope is only to allow tests to run, but not yet to provide a comprehensive API for users." 2) JS and DOM are two separate things. The JS package allows you to make calls to JS functions, it does not include a complete Go implementation of JS DOM. 3) The Wiki link you posted suggests using https://github.com/dennwc/dom for DOM manipulation. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. I looked at the DOM library. It will probably be useful later but I like to avoid extra packages while I'm still taking baby steps.  For now, icza's answer meets my needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the value of any property of some JavaScript object, use the [`Value.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Get) method (you actually already used it when you accessed the document object by calling `js.Global().Get("document")`). Similarly, to set a value of a property, use [`Value.Set()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value.Set).

The name of the property whose value to get / set is simply a Go `string` value, `"innerHTML"` in your case. The value to be set may be many of Go values (e.g. `string`, integer numbers, floating point numbers, `bool`, slices, maps etc.), the [`js.ValueOf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#ValueOf) function is used to obtain a [`js.Value()`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/js/#Value) that will be set ultimately. In your case, you may simply use the Go `string` value `"Dynamic Content"`.

```
doc := js.Global().Get("document")
body := doc.Call("getElementById", "thebody")
body.Set("innerHTML", "Dynamic Content")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked after I fixed the typo in the last line. Should be `body.Set ` instead of `body.SetValue`.

Comment: @MikeEllis Yes, it's `body.Set()`. Thanks.